# How can I display the number of songs in a UILabel in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, itunes

How can I count songs from the iTunes library and display the number of songs in a `UILabel` using Objective C ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
MPMediaQuery *fullList = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init];
//You could add a predicate to filter out what you (don't) need, for example if you don't cloud items: 
//[fullList addFilterPredicate:[MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyIsCloudItem]];
NSArray *mediaList = [fullList items];

UILabel *numberOfSongs = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 200)];
numberOfSongs.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li",mediaList.count];
[self.view addSubview:numberOfSongs];
```

Comment: Thanks for answering ...i have one more question.. if i have to count song  through artist group?

Comment: Than you need to add a predicate filter like:
        [fullList addFilterPredicate:[MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:@"Green Day" forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist comparisonType:MPMediaPredicateComparisonContains]];

Comment: i found the result 0 songs

Comment: Done, see above. You need to add it before initializing the array mediaList.

Comment: MPMediaQuery *fullList = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init];
    //You could add a predicate to filter out what you (don't) need, for example if you don't cloud items:
    [fullList addFilterPredicate:[MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist]];
    NSArray *mediaList = [fullList items];
    
    
    
    
    
    myCell.songCount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li",(unsigned long)mediaList.count];

Comment: and i found result 0

Answer (score -1):

For finding all songs of an artist you could do this:

```
//The artist you want to find
NSString *artistToFind = @"Green day";

//Perform the query
MPMediaQuery *fullList = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init];
[fullList addFilterPredicate:[MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:artistToFind forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist comparisonType:MPMediaPredicateComparisonContains]];
NSArray *mediaList = [fullList items];

//Log the total result
NSLog(@"%@ Tracks found for artist: %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li",(unsigned long)mediaList.count],artistToFind);

//Log the individual results
for(int i=0; i<mediaList.count; i++){
    NSLog(@"Track: %@",[mediaList[i] valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply; i asked for all artists not for single artist just like itunes.

Comment: Its done thankx alot. your code really help full for me

Comment: You're welcome! For more detailed information you could dive into [the MPMediaQuery Class Referenc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaQuery_ClassReference/)